# Material-UI: Can I change SnackBar's ClickAwayListener's defaultProp mouseEvent from 'onMouseUp'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's [Snackbar](https://material-ui.com/api/snackbar/). It has a `ClickAwayListener` inside it.

`ClickAwayListener` has a default prop `mouseEvent` that is set to `'onMouseUp'`. I want it to be set to `'onMouseDown'`.

If I was using the ClickAwayListener directly, I would do something

```
<ClickAwayListener mouseEvent={'onMouseDown'}/>
```

Since I'm simply using Snackbar:

```
<Snackbar {...this.props.options}
    open={this.props.state}
    onClose={this.props.hideMessage}
    (etc)
/>
```

I don't have this sort of opportunity. Is there a way to set this value, or do I need to submit this as an issue to the Material-UI github repo? I see they set a [TransitionProps](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Snackbar/Snackbar.js#L266) to pass into the transition component, so I feel they just didn't implement it.

I looked for perhaps a way to set overrides for the defaults, but the MUI documentation was only talking about style overrides.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to pass mouseEvent="onMouseDown" through ClickAwayListenerProps={}

Comment: But based on the docs i believe you can only turn off mouseEvents https://material-ui.com/api/click-away-listener/

Comment: Haha your answer is definitely right now - I created the PR that introduced that ClickAwayListenerProps to pass props through the same way they do it for TransitionProps: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12727. And no, you have more than just turning off mouseEvents: `enum: 'onClick' | 'onMouseDown' |  'onMouseUp' | false`